# bootstrap giving a margin to div without new line

Tags: bootstrap-4

```css
.box {
  background-color:red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


   
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 box">Box1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 box">Box2
    </div>
</div>
</div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

There is no problem to the above. But when i add margin to the divs, second div goes to the next line.

```css
.box {
  margin: 0px 1px;
  background-color:red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

How to fix this problem. Why the bootstrap does not allow to adding some margin. Do you have any idea to fix this using by bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `margin` with `.col-*`. It breaks bootstrap's layout. By default,

```
col-md-6 + col-md-6 = row 
50%      +  50% = 100%
```

But when you use `margin`

```
(col-md-6 + margin ) + (col-md-6 + margin ) > row 
( 50 %  + 1px )  + (50 % + 1px) > 100%
```

---

Add another element inside column and use margin on it.

```css
.box {
  margin: 0px 1px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="box">
        Box1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="box">
        Box2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

actually, in bootstrap, all attributes are important so you should better add class
 `m-t, m-b, m-r, m-l` or make the important for every attribute.